# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote the following rules to redirect to lowercase url if any character in the url is upper case

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . https://www.example.com${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

The above rule can redirect https://www.example.com/HelloWorld to https://www.example.com/helloworld

This above rule worked perfectly but then I wanted to defer the lowercasing for all urls which corresponds to actual file urls. For example I wanted to defer the above rule for

https://www.example.com/ABC.png if ABC.png file actually exists on the server.

To do this I added the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` as below

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . https://www.example.com${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```

Despite the above change https://www.example.com/ABC.png is getting redirected to ttps://www.example.com/abc.png. This should be very straight forward but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. When you are using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` in the context of virtual host you should write it as `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. So the overall rule will be in this case

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule . https://www.example.com${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [R=301,L]
```